# Brace range expansion of three variables

Tags: bash, brace-expansion

I'm not sure if I've used the correct terminology in the title and in this question so please edit it if it's incorrect.

In a bash script I have three arrays, `dirs`, `files`, and `extensions`. How can I make all combinations of strings that contain a value from `dirs`, then `files`, and then `extensions`?

I'm not experienced with Bash at all, but I did try this to see if I could achieve this with just two arrays:

```
$ echo ${dirs[@]}
a b
$ echo ${files[@]}
c d
$ echo ${dirs[@]}{${files[@]}}
a bc d
```

The output I want from this example is `ac bc ad bd`

EDIT: I completely screwed up the example and just fixed it, in case you were wondering what happened.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this with `{foo,bar}` syntax; bash only expands that if it sees *literal* commas between the braces.  (I suppose you could use `eval`, but that brings its own mess.)

Just use loops:

```
for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; do
    for file in "${files[@]}"; do
        for ext in "${extensions[@]}"; do
            echo "$dir$file$ext"
        done
    done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

**The following will work in all conditions where brace expansion conditions are satisfied**

```
$ dirs=(a b)
$ files=(c d)

$ eval echo {${dirs[0]}..${dirs[$((${#dirs[@]}-1))]}}{${files[0]}..${files[$((${#files[@]}-1))]}}
ac ad bc bd
```

For your more understanding:

```
$ A=`echo {${dirs[0]}..${dirs[$((${#dirs[@]}-1))]}}`
$ B=`echo {${files[0]}..${files[$((${#files[@]}-1))]}}`
$ echo $A$B
{a..b}{c..d}
$ eval echo $A$B
ac ad bc bd
```

Comment: This only works if the arrays contain consecutive sequences of letters -- it works for the example in the question, but probably not for a real application.

Comment: This will work in all conditions where brace expansion conditions are satisfied. If gsingh2011's inputs satisfy brace expansion conditions, then this is OK. Other wise better to use for loops. Also he tagged the question with `brace-expansion` and hence I think this will help him.

Comment: @gsingh2011 . Always try to accept the answer which fulfilled your requirement. Points are like motivation for all who are actively answering here. Also in that way this thread can consider as a completed one.

Answer (score 0):

This is inspired by @Suku's answer, but uses `{a,b,c}`-style expansion instead of `{a..c}`:

```
$ dirs=(this/ that/)
$ files=(a b c)
$ extensions=(.c .h)
$ saveIFS=$IFS
$ IFS=,
$ eval echo "{${dirs[*]}}{${files[*]}}{${extensions[*]}}"
this/a.c this/a.h this/b.c this/b.h this/c.c this/c.h that/a.c that/a.h that/b.c that/b.h that/c.c that/c.h
$ IFS=$saveIFS
```

Note that as with almost anything involving `eval`, this can fail catastrophically if any of the array values have the wrong metacharacters. If this is a concern, use @Eevee's answer instead.